# Socket error when writing to socket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

I have the following code:

```
  # Connect to neighbors and send hello message
  current_node.neighbors_addresses.each do |address| 
    for i in 0..10
      begin
        sock = TCPSocket.new(address, 3000)
        break
      rescue Errno::EHOSTUNREACH, Errno::ECONNREFUSED
        puts "before sleep"
        sleep(2)
        puts "after sleep"
      end
    end
    sock.write("Hi from node #{current_node.name}\n")
  end
```

The current_node is a node object with neighbors_addresses as an instance variable that stores the ip addresses of the neighbors of the current node.

The problem is, the line `sock.write("Hi from node #{current_node.name}\n")`gives the error:

```
server1.rb:211:in `block in main': undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from server1.rb:200:in `each'
    from server1.rb:200:in `main'
    from server1.rb:276:in `<main>'
```

If write is not a method in the socket class then how do you write to that socket?

Comment: Put `sock.write` just after `sock = TCPSocket...` ?

Comment: WOuld that really work?

Comment: @umdcoder if the code of `rescue` gets executed 10 times, `sock` will be `nil` after the for-loop ends. You need to make sure `sock` is a `Socket` object before calling any method or accessing any attribute of the object itself. SeanNieuwoudt is right.

Answer (score 0):

Put `sock.write` just after `sock = TCPSocket...` ?
                    – SeanNieuwoudt

if the code of `rescue` gets executed 10 times, `sock` will be `nil` after the for-loop ends. You need to make sure `sock` is a `Socket` object before calling any method or accessing any attribute of the object itself. SeanNieuwoudt is right.
                    – yeyo